# robot_localization how to set up tf

Tags: ros, imu, navigation, ptam, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My understanding of a fundamental concept is way off somewhere and was hoping someone could set me straight :)

I am trying to use robot_localization to fuse PTAM+IMU.

I have read through the docs and tutorials for the robot localization package but I am still new to ROS so I am having trouble understanding how tf works with robot_localization.

I have an IMU topic publishing from a pixhawk via mavros: /mavros/imu/data

and I also have a ptam topic: /vslam/pose

Lets say that the orientation of both sensors are aligned with a positional offset on the y of 50cm.

I am guessing that I am now suppose to set up a tf system in code that represents the physical model (with the 50cm offset) and then broadcast the tf system so that robot_localization can use it. Is that correct?

Or am I suppose to use the frame_ids provided by the sensors?

Also if anyone knows of any step by step tutorials for something like this then please let me know. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Ok so I tried using the frame_ids from the sensor messages and put those in the launch file for robot_localization. usb_cam is the frame_id from the /vslam/pose and fcu is from /mavros/imu/data. I'm not using a map frame.

`<param name="odom_frame" value="usb_cam"/>`

`<param name="base_link_frame" value="fcu"/>`

`<param name="world_frame" value="usb_cam"/>`

Now robot_localization publishes to the /odometry/filtered topic. When I view the tf tree on rviz it doesn't look right but I am thinking that I have not aligned the axes right?

I've been trying to get this right but still not sure if this is even the right way to use robot_localization?!?!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216750/robot_localization-how-to-set-up-tf/) by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2015-08-30

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would start by reading through [REP-105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html), and also the [tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf) wiki page.

Your odometry frame_id is typically "odom" and is a world-referenced frame. In other words, if you start your robot and drive it forward five meters and left 3 meters, your position in the *odom* frame should be (5, 3). However, your position in this frame is subject to drift (e.g., just fusing wheel encoders and IMU data).

Your map frame_id is typically "map" and is identical to the odom frame, except that your position in the map frame is not guaranteed to be continuous, and is *not* subject to drift over time. For example, if you are including GPS data, your position will probably jump around a bit, but over time, your position in that frame will be more accurate than a position estimate that only used wheel encoders and IMUs.

The base_link frame_id is typically "base_link" and is rigidly affixed to your robot. Most velocity (twist) data is reported in this frame. For example, a simple differential drive wheeled robot can only have +/- X and +/- yaw velocity.

For your problem, you need to make sure each message has a frame_id specified, and then make sure you produce a transform (e.g., via static_transform_publisher) that specifies the transform from the frame_id of the message to one of the frame_ids listed above. For IMU data, you'll need to specify a *base_link*-->*imu* transform (assuming you use those two frame_id names). For the PTAM data, the frame_id probably defaults to *map* or *odom*, but you'll have to verify that. See [this](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials/Preparing%20Your%20Sensor%20Data) tutorial for more information on preparing sensor data.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-08-31**:
Thanks for your help Tom. I've read through those links but I still don't understand the relationship between tf, the sensor frame_ids and the robot_localization launch file. Feeling really dense right now. I'll have another read, maybe something will click this time.

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-08-31**:
So I have 2 messages from third party packages and they each have a frame_id: fcu (imu) and usb_cam (ptam). Do I then make 2 tf links using static_transform_publisher: base_link->fcu and odom->usb_cam. Then in robot_localization do I reference base_link and odom in the launch file???

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-08-31**:
Still stuck. Where do these map, odom, base_link frames come from? Do I generate them?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-08-31**:
The frame_ids are just names. The transforms between them are all managed by `tf`. So you can use the `tf` library to specify a transform from frame A to frame B, and then broadcast it. Other nodes can then consume that transform by also using the `tf` libraries.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-08-31**:
So, e.g., if you have a LIDAR that is mounted on its side on your robot, and it senses an obstacle 5 meters away at 30 degrees (from the LIDAR's origin), you might need to know where that point is for the *robot's* frame, or even in the world (e.g., *odom*) coordinate frame.

**Comment by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on 2015-08-31**:
Thanks again Tom! Hope that wasn't too painful for you. I didn't know what I was missing so didn't even know the right questions to ask. I think I get it now.